# Release Kinect for Windows V2 app without needing users to install the SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, kinect, kinect-v2

My application only runs when a computer has the [Kinect for Windows V2 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect)
installed. I thought a user would only need to have [Kinect for Windows Runtime v2.0 installed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44559).

Without the SDK installed I get an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   ...

In my Visual Studios Reference Manager, I search for Kinect and all of the DLLs are from the SDK. I use

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKS\Kinect\v2.0_1409\Assemblies\Microsoft.Kinect.dll

Do I need to add a different reference from the Runtime library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can i check if you have done these steps to ensure you have already added the references into your project?
[image][image]

Cheers!

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what I did.

Comment: It could be the Files it is trying to copy upon building the application is not found on their computer as seen in this code below:
xcopy "$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)Redist\Face\$(Platform)\NuiDatabase" "$(TargetDir)\NuiDatabase" /S /R /Y /I
Which can be found under Project > Project Properties > Build events > Post-Build.
what the code does is basically copying some files over from the kinect sdk folder to your project. let me know if this helps